# Update query: subquery returned more than 1 value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to update a table (`Yahoostockdata)` with information extracted from another table (`incomestatement`), depending on the date.

`Yahoostockdata` contains Yahoo prices per day and I'd like to add the number of shares per date depending on the most actual information available in `incomestatement`  for that specific date.

When running the query (without the update) I get all the numbers I want. Except, when adding the `UPDATE` statement, I get the error message: *suquery returned more than 1 value*.

*Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression. The statement has been terminated.*

Can anyone help me to solve this issue? I already had a look at related questions, but could not find an answer. Thank you in advance. Below the code I'm using:

```
Update YahooStockData
Set NumberOfShares = (Select [Weighted average shares outstanding (Diluted)]
   from (Select *,ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by derived_1.MorningstarTicker,
             derived_1.[date] order by derived_1.AsOfDate desc) as RN
         from (Select Yahoostockdata.YahooTicker, IncomeStatement.MorningstarTicker,
               yahoostockdata.[Date], AsOfDate, 
               Incomestatement.[Weighted average shares outstanding (Diluted)]
               from IncomeStatement INNER JOIN
                  YahooStockData ON IncomeStatement.MorningstarTicker = YahooStockData.MorningstarTicker
         Where  YahooStockData.[Date] >= AsOfDate) as derived_1) as derived_2
    Where RN = 1)
```

Comment: Is there something you don't understand about "subquery returns more than 1 value"?  The subquery is returning multiple rows.  You can naively fix this by using `top 1` in the `select` or using an aggregation function such as `min()` or `max()`.  However, you might want some control over which value is actually chosen.

Comment: Gordon, thank you for your quick reply. the Top 1 etc. would indeed not solve it. Basically the query gives me an exact copy of all lines that should be pasted in the yahoostockdata table. I would appreciate any ideas or good practices how I can solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
UPDATE A
SET    NumberOfShares = B.[Weighted average shares outstanding (Diluted)]
FROM   YahooStockData A
       JOIN (SELECT [Weighted average shares outstanding (Diluted)],
                    derived_2.MorningstarTicker
             FROM   (SELECT *,
                            Row_number() OVER ( partition BY  derived_1.MorningstarTicker, derived_1.[date]
                                ORDER BY derived_1.AsOfDate DESC) AS RN
                     FROM   (SELECT Yahoostockdata.YahooTicker,
                                    IncomeStatement.MorningstarTicker,
                                    yahoostockdata.[Date],
                                    AsOfDate,
                                    Incomestatement.[Weighted average shares outstanding (Diluted)]
                             FROM   IncomeStatement
                                    INNER JOIN YahooStockData
                                            ON IncomeStatement.MorningstarTicker = YahooStockData.MorningstarTicker
                             WHERE  YahooStockData.[Date] >= AsOfDate) AS derived_1) AS derived_2
             WHERE  RN = 1) B
         ON A.MorningstarTicker = B.MorningstarTicker
```

Comment: That's working great, thx. I only had to add another join column (i.e. A.date = B.date). Unfortunately, the query runs pretty slow, so any ideas on how to make it faster would be welcome. I've now added a clustered key on date and ticker.

Answer (score 1):

This could be cleaned up further, but I believe this is what you're after:

```
;WITH cte AS (Select MorningstarTicker,[Weighted average shares outstanding (Diluted)]
                from (Select *,ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by derived_1.MorningstarTicker,
                             derived_1.[date] order by derived_1.AsOfDate desc) as RN
                      from (Select Yahoostockdata.YahooTicker, IncomeStatement.MorningstarTicker,
                                    yahoostockdata.[Date], AsOfDate, 
                                    Incomestatement.[Weighted average shares outstanding (Diluted)]
                            from IncomeStatement 
                            INNER JOIN   YahooStockData ON IncomeStatement.MorningstarTicker = YahooStockData.MorningstarTicker
                            Where  YahooStockData.[Date] >= AsOfDate
                            ) as derived_1
                    ) as derived_2
                Where RN = 1)
                )
UPDATE a
SET a.NumberofShares = b.[Weighted average shares outstanding (Diluted)]
FROM YahooStockData a
JOIN cte b
  ON a.MorningstarTicker = b.MorningstarTicker
```

I've added `MorningstartTicker` to your subquery and put the whole bit into a cte just to make the `UPDATE` with a `JOIN` easier to see.

The problem with your original query is that you were attempting to update every record with one value, because they weren't related to the subquery.

Comment: That's working great, thx. I only had to add another join column (i.e. A.date = B.date). Unfortunately, the query runs pretty slow, so any ideas on how to make it faster would be welcome. I've now added a clustered key on date and ticker. In general, does a CTE work faster than what Pradeep proposed?

Comment: Apparently, I can only flag 1 answer as being correct, although both are working.

Comment: @Xivan I imagine the execution plan is identical, I just thought the cte made it easier to see the update with a join structure.